# JetBrains Rider #region defaults in Structure pane

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

In Rider, C# `#regions` will be shown as auto-collapsed in the Structure pane. If you open the region in the structure pane then make any edit anywhere in the open file they auto-collapse again.

Is there any way to change this behavior? I'd like to default them open and edits to not make any difference to the collapse state.

Answer (score 4):

you can change this in Preferences | Editor | General | Code Folding

Comment: My understanding is that these will only change code folding in the edit window - toggling the 'preprocessor regions' tickbox in there makes no difference to how the structure panel handles state.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. Code Structure node shouldn't collapse on the document modifications. Filed an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-8665